# IllegalMonitorStateException not thrown where it should

Tags: eclipse, multithreading, wait

While studying for OJP I came to the topic of Thread wait() method and so on, According to the book, this portion of code should throw IllegalMonitorStateException since the wait() is invoked on an object other than the one synchronized on, but I doesn't with me, Any Idea?

```
public class Syncho {

public  void synchoTest(){
    ThreadTest test1 = new ThreadTest();
    ThreadTest test2 = new ThreadTest();
    ThreadTest test3 = new ThreadTest();
    ThreadTest test4 = new ThreadTest();
    ThreadTest test5 = new ThreadTest();

    test1.start();
    test2.start();
    synchronized(test1){
        try{
            System.out.println("gere");
            //test1 = new ThreadTest();
            //test1.start();
            wait();
            System.out.println("tere");
        }catch(Exception x){}
    }
    //notify();
    test3.start();
    test4.start();
    test5.start();



}
```

}

actually "gere" only is printed not "tere"

I am using eclipse with java 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, an exception *is* being thrown, for exactly the reason you describe - you're just catching it and swallowing it:

```
catch(Exception x){}
```

Don't do that. *Never* do that. Just doing this:

```
catch (Exception x) {
    x.printStackTrace();
}
```

... will show you the exception being thrown.

Comment: @OsamaYaccoub: Ah, I see. Okay, to reproduce this, could you show us what `ThreadTest` looks like? A short but complete example would really help.

Comment: @OsamaYaccoub: Looking at it again, I'm pretty sure an exception *is* being thrown, but you're catching it and doing absolutely nothing with it.

Comment: I am just running it in eclipse .... nothing is thrown in the console .... concerning  'ThreadTest' It just contains a single 'System.out.println' ... just a test

Comment: I wonder if eclipse has some settings to avoid throwing RuntimeExceptions or something like that .. I don't think so, But I am just wondering

Comment: @OsamaYaccoub: Well why would you expect anything to be shown in the console, when you're swallowing the exception? You've *explicitly* caught `Exception` and done *absolutely nothing with it* - no logging, no rethrowing, nothing. It's doing exactly what you've told it to do.